# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [checkout, build, deploy]

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to do parallel stages dynamically, hence defining the to be stage names inside a list. Getting the above error.

Below is my code:

```
pipeline{
  agent any
  stages{
    stage('Integration Tests'){
      steps{
        script {
            doDynamicParallelSteps()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

def doDynamicParallelSteps(){
   tests = ['checkout', 'build', 'deploy']
   for (f in tests) {
       node {
           stage("${f}") {
               echo '${f}'
           }
       }
   }
   parallel tests
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tests` in your example is a list of strings, while `parallel` expects a map of type `[name1 : code block 1,  name2 : code block 2...]`

Can you try something like this?

```
def doDynamicParallelSteps(){
  stages = ['checkout', 'build', 'deploy']
  tests = [:]

  for (f in stages) {
      tests[f] = make_step(f)
  }

  parallel tests
}

def make_step(tag) {
    return {
        node {
            stage("${tag}") {
                  echo "${tag}"
              }
          }  
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, it seems to evaluate `${f}` when the method is called, not when it is created. I'm updating the answer with something I've tested

Comment: I'm going to run it in slaves with particular labels. Where should I do the agent definition? Right now if I add it under stage in pipeline block, it just selects one particular node and fails because simultaneously multiple git processes of all the parallel stages gets triggered and index.lock file gets created. Requirement is : It should run in different nodes of same label.

stage('Integration Tests'){
     agent { label 'integration'}